# vim move a block of selected code up or down

Tags: linux, unix, vim

There is a way to move highlighted code up or down with arrow keys. Even the indentation would be correct on dropping the block.

For the life of me I do not remember how to do it.

Can someone please tell me how to do it.( suitably embarrassed asking this).

Comment: Note that there is now a [vi/vim community](http://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 7):

Here's the link that'll help you

[link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_lines_up_or_down)

You can move a line, or a block of lines, with the :m command. Examples:

***:m 12***  move current line to after line 12

To move a block of lines, use the same command but visually select the lines before entering the move command. You can also use arbitrary ranges with the move command. Examples:

***:5,7m 21***   move lines 5, 6 and 7 to after line 21

Answer (score 1):

why not use `d+p` if you had chosen the block code

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful: I'm not very familiar with vim, but it sounds like he's talking about delete and paste, or some such. Poorly phrased, but valid, if so.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with arrow keys, you can try Tim Pope's [vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) plugin, which you can find on Github.

Then you can use mappings similar to these (except map them to whatever keys you like).

```
" ^U moves lines up, ^D moves lines down.
" Works in normal or visual select modes.
nmap <C-u> [e
nmap <C-d> ]e
vmap <C-u> [egv
vmap <C-d> ]egv
```

Answer (score 1):

Cutting a block of text in visual mode and then pasting:

1. Go to command mode by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> if you're not already in it
2. Move to the start or end of where you want to go
3. Press <kbd>V</kbd> to switch to visual mode
4. Move with arrows or <kbd>H,J,K,L</kbd> to the other end of the block you want to move
5. Press <kbd>D</kbd> to cut it, it will switch back into command mode
6. Move to where you want to put it and press <kbd>P</kbd> to paste what you cut

It seems like a lot of steps but it's just a verbose explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my configurations, There is a nice configuration that I am using to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to move a block of code up and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to move a block down. I am using currently NVIM but I think the same configuration setting is applicable for VIM as well.

- Setting on NVIM
  The location that I am using on macOS Catalina for the NVIM is located at:

  **.config/nvim/init.vim**

```sh
    nnoremap K :m .-2<CR>==
    nnoremap J :m .+1<CR>==
    vnoremap K :m '<-2<CR>gv==gv
    vnoremap J :m '>+1<CR>gv=gv
```

for vim I think you can change the setting on
`.vimrc` located under the home directory.